# Map dictionary with variable key

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I have a dictionary with a variable key, so I'm having trouble mapping it. My JSON looks like:

```
{
    "2396": [{
        "id": 21313,
        "sId": 43847
    }, {
        "id": 21314,
        "sId": 43841
    }],
    "2397": [{
        "id": 43237,
        "sId": 37321
    }, {
        "id": 43231,
        "sId": 37342
    }]
}
```

Any suggestions? I've tried ObjectMapper, AlamofireToJson and such.

Alamofire gives me this, however it seems not like a dictionary compared to the one above:

```
    {
    2396 = ( {
            id = "21313";
            sid = "43847";
        },
       {
            id = "21314";
            sid = "43841";
        }
    );
2397 = ( {
            id = "43237";
           sid = "37321";
        },
                {
           id = "43231";
           sid = "37342";
        }
);
}
```

With the following call:

```
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params, headers: headers())
            .responseJSON{response in
print(response.result.value)
}
```

I want to map the above JSON into a dictionary, but can figure out how to.

Comment: Map to what? What are you trying to do with the data? You can simply enumerate keys and values...

Comment: How to map this to a dictionary using Alamofire for instance.

Comment: you want to keep `2396` and  `2397` values too?

Comment: Yea, exactly. That's IDs.

Comment: Anything that can parse JSON should have no problem with this. You can use the standard `JSONObjectWithData` method of the `NSJSONSerialization` class, it'll return a dictionary (which in turn contains arrays, which contain more dictionaries).

Comment: which swift version are you using?

Comment: Using Swift3. Can I do it with Alamofire? I've updated my question, because I think the JSON I get from Alamofire seems odd.

Comment: It's not odd, it's exactly the same data. If you're looking for the data to be represented some other way, please state so in your question, including the exact format you would like to get. We can't guess it for you.

Comment: I just want the JSON from the Alamfire put into a dictionary

Comment: What happens if you try to log `response.result.value["2397"]`?

Comment: Remember that the key change, they're id's.

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Two Object Classes, one `NSObject` and another `Mappable`:

```
class ID: NSObject {
    var id:String!
    var ids:[IDs]!

    init(id:String, ids:[IDs]) {
        self.id = id
        self.ids = ids
    }
}

class IDs: Mappable {
    var id: NSInteger!
    var sId: NSInteger!

    required init?(_ map: Map) {

    }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id    <- map["id"]
        sId   <- map["sId"]
    }
}
```

Sample View Controller class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dict = [
        "2396" : [
            [
                "id": 21313,
                "sId": 43847
            ], [
                "id" : 21314,
                "sId" : 43841
            ]
        ],
        "2397" : [
            [
                "id": 43237,
                "sId": 37321
            ], [
                "id": 43231,
                "sId": 37342
            ]
        ]
    ]

    var arrID:[ID]! = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        createObject()
    }

    func createObject(){
        for (key,value) in dict {
            let ids =  Mapper<IDs>().mapArray(value)!

            arrID.append(ID.init(id: key, ids: ids))
        }

        print(arrID)
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
(lldb) po arrID[0].id
"2397"

(lldb) po arrID[0].ids[0].id
43237

(lldb) po arrID[0].ids[0].sId
37321
```